# Typescript flattens array types to their element type not working inside Mapped Types

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

I have User type like below

```
interface IUserMongo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string[];
  nested: {
    name: string;
    sayYes: boolean;
    rrr: 1;
  };
}
```

I want to derive the following type

```
interface IUserMongo {
  name: number;
  age: number;
  address:number;
  nested: {
    name: number;
    sayYes: number;
    rrr: number;
  };
}
```

code is working except for arrays.

> error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'number[]'

ts playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO0CyB7EAcz2QG8AoZZEOAWwgC5lMwpRCBuS5OQx6gK60ARtC5U4AE0lQImTExZsiAbQC646nMiSmFKlRr1FrdpqqY4ATwCacpsLx4ANhDghzyKN6YBGTQC%20XAHk5GBWAA4oGNhQAApQeABWEAhgADwAKgA0yAByyAC8giLQAHxFZNwqANLIoMgA1hBWeDDImWpMmbVqyBAAHpAgkpjIeMIpacgA-GhY0AnJqRk9NWq5eRVMecFc5AgELMgRiVNgwARMMYtnK%20k3UPhEeBXF%20tR0-L7Z3Lzfvwk0lk8j8gK0LAguiqBmY1jsCmQP24hi%20YJRXh8SPBAV%20QVChxAxwEsWuCyeBGIlQ%20Rn4AHJMJJCHTwf90UCZHJESo6YQYMyNtwQNooXoMZZbPZkKwBBBwajjMg6d4oCyMSr2chceR8eQAPR66UAC2AY1NxpQoiNcAAbpcoPVkAB3dxgcigSCwRAoHACZwXADCBDAcFA0BhaEgtF8JmUhHUmlQUYATEwQEJRFAEzrQuEosgAMrsVxB8Ch4UO97IFRxeogJotNrIX3%204ClkNhqBdEqZrX7QnHMBgJhFogl4Pl8PvUKwpMQaOaqhz2ip7E6rhAA)

```
interface IUserMongo {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string[];
  nested: {
    name: string;
    sayYes: boolean;
    rrr: 1;
  };
}

type IUserProject<T, N = number> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? IUserProject<T[K], N> : N;
};

const projection: IUserProject<IUserMongo> = {
  name: 1,
  age: 1,
  address: 1,
  nested: {
    sayYes: 1,
    name: 1,
    rrr: 1,
  },
};

const user: IUserMongo = {
  name: 'sdg',
  age: 1,
  address: ['gfg'],
  nested: {
    sayYes: true,
    name: 'rrr',
    rrr: 1,
  },
};

// this is the behavior i want
interface MultiContainer {
  Item1: string[];
  Item2: number[];
}

type SingleContainer = { [P in keyof MultiContainer]: number };

const tt: SingleContainer = {

    Item1: 1,
    Item2: 1,
};
```

Comment: Add a special case for arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if it's an array:

```
type IUserProject<T, N = number> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends object ? T[K] extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> ? N : IUserProject<T[K], N> : N;
};
```

[Works now](https://tsplay.dev/m3663N)